# Pandas check that a list is is_monotonic_increasing but with specific step

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Lets say that we have these columns in a df:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  0  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  4  4
3  4  6  6
4  5  8  8
```

I know that I can check that every specific columns with monotonic_increasing like that

```
df['A'].is_monotonic_increasing.
```

I was wondering if there is a way to check/validate that the monotonic_increasing has a specific step. Let me explain. I would like for example to check that `df['A']` is monotonic_increasing with step 1, the `df['B']` is monotonic_increasing with step 2.

Is there a way to check that out ?

Comment: exactly a step of 1, or at least a step of 1?

Comment: Something like `df.C.is_monotonic_increasing & (df.C.diff() == 2)`, but the first row of `.diff()` is always `False`. So `(df.A.is_monotonic_increasing & (df.A.diff() == 1)).iloc[1:].all()`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a function for that. We can build a two-line function:

```
def step_incr(series, step=1):
    tmp = np.arange(len(series)) * step
    return series.eq(series.iloc[0]+tmp).all()

step_incr(df['A'], step=1)
# True

step_incr(df['B'], step=1)
# False
```

Another way to check is looking at the values of differences:

```
def is_step(series):
    uniques = series.diff().iloc[1:].unique()

    if len(uniques) == 1:
        return True, uniques[0]
    return False, None

is_step(df['A'])
# (True, 1.0)

is_step(df['B'])
# (True, 2.0)

is_step(df['C'])
# (False, None)
```

Comment: I think the answer needs to explain what the function is doing, which is building an array of the same size with a given step, and then comparing that to the series.

Answer (score 0):

One liner to get all columns at once:

```
 df.diff().iloc[1] * (df.diff().nunique() == 1)
```

Output:

```
A    1.0
B    2.0
C    0.0
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Output is the step size, or 0 if not monotonic increasing.